# How can I access each document id in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my blogapp  ,I am trying to implement comment system in flutter using cloud firestore. Each document is a post and I am trying to add comments as a subcollection to each document. **How can I access each document id** so that I can access the subcollection ?

Here I tried to print the document id below but it shows error `NoSuchMethodError: 'id' method not found Receiver: null Arguments: []` :

```
 final ref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('blogs')
                            .add({
                              'title': titleController.text,
                              'body': myController.text,
                              'author': name,
                              'date': DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm')
                                  .format(DateTime.now()),
                            })
                            .then((value) => successAlert(context))
                            .catchError((error) => 
                        errorAlert(context));
                        titleController.clear();
                        myController.clear();
                        print(ref.id);
                      }
```

This is my firestore database :

[image]

Comment: Is this a data setup thing, or in your blogging app, is a user allowed to comment on all posts at once?  Anyway, to do something to a doc, you need its ref, and to get all docs (not sure if you mean "all" when you say "each"), form the broadest query and get: `await query(collection(db, "blogs")).getDocs()`

Comment: How is your front-end designed? I guess that to create a comment a user has to somehow trigger the creation from the parent post (like clicking on a button in the parent post screen )?

Comment: I need to access these random document ids so that I can access the subcollection. I tried "ref.id' ,but it is not working

Comment: The issue here is not clear. It's normal for documentId's to be 'random' but if a user is adding a comment to the post (a document), they would have selected the post they want to add the comment to in the UI already, right? In order for them to select that post, you would have already read in the posts to display them; therefore you would already have the documentId of each one. So.... what's the issue? Perhaps you forgot to keep track of the post documentId when they were read in for display?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to the document id inside blogs, and access it's collection and the add your data like this...

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('blogs')
                            .doc(documentId) // you need to enter this document id
                            .collection('comments').add({
                              'title': titleController.text,
                              'body': myController.text,
                              'author': name,
                              'date': DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm')
                                  .format(DateTime.now()),
                            })
```

Comment: I know..but my document ids are just random and thats my problem .

Comment: Then you need to do some changes there, store the document id generated inside users collection and using UserModel if you are using models, or get document id everytime and access the comments

Answer (score 0):

When you dont have the document id Firebase provides the [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) command which returns the content of a collection. Like this:

```
db.collection("cities").get().then((res) => print("Successfully completed"), onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"));
```

But i realize that you will need the document id, so to get this you have to store the id after inserting a post, i've an example from a personal project:

```
await firestore.collection('item').add({
      'quantity': element.quantity,
      'product_id': element.product.productId,
    }).then((value) {
      /// Here you can access [value.id] to get this document id.
      /// Now you can save it in a list or a class instance. Just keep it.
    })
```

Now you can use the document id to update the post with a new comment, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033361/18496272). For more information we have the [Firestore documentation with flutter code snipets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).